# App wont run unless you update google play services error on real device

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Auth for my app, in some devices it throws me that error, my firebase dependencies are 9.6.1.

**1**:Can i do something against this?

**2**:The onComplete never gets called so i cant know if the user doesnt support this, how could i handle it?

**3**:Are there a lot of devices with version of google play services lower than that?

Thanks

Comment: So, what is stopping you from upgrading Google Play Services?

Comment: Nothing, i can update it on my phone, but not in users phones

Comment: Then that sounds like a user problem. If they want to use your app, they must upgrade

Comment: Android device owners are expected to have up-to-date versions of Play Services on their devices.  Nearly all Android devices update to the latest versions within a couple weeks of availability.  It's generally not a good idea to assume that your users do not update - if they don't update, they are going to have lots of other problems anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During app initialization, your code should call [GoogleApiAvailability.makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.app.Activity)). The invoked processing:

> Attempts to make Google Play services available on this device. If
>   Play Services is already available, the returned Task may complete
>   immediately.
>
> If it is necessary to display UI in order to complete this request
>   (e.g. sending the user to the Google Play store) the passed Activity
>   will be used to display this UI.
>
> It is recommended to call this method from onCreate(Bundle). If the
>   passed Activity completes before the returned Task completes, the Task
>   will fail with a CancellationException.

Example use in `onCreate()` of  main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Play Services OKAY");
                } else {
                    // Show the user some UI explaining that the needed version
                    // of Play Services could not be installed and the app can't run.
                }
            }
    });

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend lowering the Google Play Services version you use in your app: unless you specifically need something in a later version of Play Services? It shouldn't cause a problem for your app, but should solve the issue with users needing an update.

Comment: Should i do it by lowering the firebase versions?